# Exception while running the ycsb load command in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, ycsb

I loaded the latest cassandra package from datastax website. Also downloaded the ycsb files from github. I am running the Ubuntu in VMware and put these files in mounted folder from windows.
Then i ran the cassandra, in background. Made the 'usertable' keyspace and 'data' column family.
And then i ran the following command:

```
"./bin/ycsb load cassandra-7 -P workloads/workloada -p hosts=127.0.0.1 -s -t"
```

But i am getting error while executing this command.

*YCSB Client 0.1

Command line: -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient7 -P workloads/workloada -p hosts=127.0.0.1 -s -t -load

Loading workload...

Starting test.

 0 sec: 0 operations; 

Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.thrift.meta_data.FieldValueMetaData.(BZ)V
    
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ColumnParent.(ColumnParent.java:146)
    
at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient7.init(CassandraClient7.java:95)
    
at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
    
at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:189)

[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 99.0

[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 0.0
 
0 sec: 0 operations; 

shan@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs/Files/Nuclear/ycsb-0.1.4$* 

(screenshot attached)

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is the reason for this error?

Comment: I get the same error if I run the command as "./bin/ycsb load cassandra-7 -P workloads/workloada -p hosts=localhost -s -t".

Answer (score 0):

`./bin/ycsb load cassandra-7 -P workloads/workloada -p hosts=10.x.x.x -s -t`

you need to put the machines ip address in hosts.
and even change the rpc_address to either 127.0.0.1 or ur machines ip
in cassandra.yaml config file.
it worked for me.